# Will it act as a voltage follower?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

[image: the problem]

Can anybody tell me the output voltage? Will it act as a voltage follower and the output is 2 volt or the virtual ground concept comes into play and the output becomes 0 volt?

Comment: Is the non-inverting input supposed to be grounded, or open like you show? Is this an ideal op amp (if not, it's impossible to say without showing the supply voltages)?

Comment: You have the input signal connected to the wrong opamp input.

Comment: The circuit is incomplete, nobody can say what it does and what is the output voltage.

Comment: Circuit is incomplete. No connections to non-inverting input.

Comment: No. For a voltage follower, take the input to the IN+ terminal. (the feedback connection is then OK)

Answer (score 3):

That is not a valid op-amp circuit. You can't leave either input floating (not connected).

There are hundreds of thousands of articles on basic op-amp theory on the Internet and in all standard texts on the subject so there is no need to explain it here. Do your research on inverting and non-inverting amplifier circuits.

Answer (score 2):

The output will be saturated at either the amplifier negative supply, or the positive supply, depending on the sign of the bias current at the unconnected positive input.